# Correctly handling UI Logic inside of a Composable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to create a list of items that shows if something needs to download. If something needs to be downloaded I want to show a button for the user to click which will kick off the download and show a circular progress bar in its place until it is finished. The Composable listens to a `StateFlow` to tell when the download has either finished successfully or failed with an error and will turn off the progress bar and show the button again if needed.

```
//Composable for the List Item UI
@Composable
fun DownloadItem(info: Info) {

    var isDownloading by remember { mutableStateOf(false)}
    var isDownloadAvailable by remember { mutableStateOf(info.downloadAvailable) }
    val composableScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val downloadState : DownloadState by downloadService.downloadStateFlow.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    when(downloadState){
        is DownloadState.Successful -> {

            //Hide button and progress bar

            info.downloadAvailable = false
            isDownloading = false
        }
        is DownloadState.Failed -> {

            //Hide progress bar but show button again

            isDownloading = false
            isDownloadAvailable = true
        }
        else -> {}
    }

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(50.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {

        Image(
            bitmap = info.icon,
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(40.dp)
                .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
                .padding(start = 8.dp)
        )

        Text(
            text = info.name,
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
                .padding(start = 8.dp),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Start, color = Color.White
        )

        Text(
            text = info.version,
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
                .padding(start = 8.dp),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Start, color = Color.White
        )

        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
            .padding(end = 8.dp)){

            if (isDownloadAvailable && !isDownloading) {
                TextButton(onClick = {
                    composableScope.launch {
                        isDownloading = true
                        try{
                            download(info) //Starts the download
                        }catch (e: Exception){
                            e.printStackTrace()
                            isDownloading = false
                        }
                    }
                  }, modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 8.dp)) {
                    Text("Download")
                }
            }

            if(isDownloading){
               CircularProgressIndicator(modifier = Modifier
                   .size(45.dp)
                   .align(Alignment.Center)
                   .padding(top = 8.dp, end = 16.dp))
            }
        }
    }

}
```

What I am not sure about how to handle is how to handle all the different button/progress bar states in combination with the flow

```
when(downloadState){
        is DownloadState.Successful -> {

            //Hide button and progress bar

            info.downloadAvailable = false
            isDownloading = false
        }
        is DownloadState.Failed -> {

            //Hide progress bar but show button again

            isDownloading = false
            isDownloadAvailable = true
        }
        else -> {}
    }
```

As I understand it doing logic inside a composable like this will cause it to recompose several times and I am not sure that is the correct way to go about what I am trying to do and I might be making the composable do extra unnecessary work.

Is this correct or is there a better more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So:

> doing logic inside a composable like this will cause it to recompose
> several times

The logic, I assume, we're talking about is the one in which we update the state.

```
info.downloadAvailable = false // which I think should be isDownloading in both cases, not just in the DownloadState.Failed
isDownloading = false
```

First of all I would avoid managing state directly in a composable function and start using a `StateHolder` such a `ViewModel` to provide and update the state from there. But that's not gonna necessarily improve performances.

The real issue in which we could incurr is reading the state higher in the composition tree. You can read in the best practices that we want to [defer state read as much a possible](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/bestpractices#defer-reads).

So, what we can actually do, is avoid reading the state in `DownloadItem` recomposition scope but actually do so in a recomposition scope lower in the recomposition tree.

How do we achieve this?

Just an example, the following code:

```
        if (isDownloadAvailable && !isDownloading) {
            TextButton(onClick = {
                composableScope.launch {
                    isDownloading = true
                    try{
                        download(info) //Starts the download
                    }catch (e: Exception){
                        e.printStackTrace()
                        isDownloading = false
                    }
                }
              }, modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 8.dp)) {
                Text("Download")
            }
        }

        if(isDownloading){
           CircularProgressIndicator(modifier = Modifier
               .size(45.dp)
               .align(Alignment.Center)
               .padding(top = 8.dp, end = 16.dp))
        }
```

Could live in a new Composable function, which would become the nearest recomposition scope in which `isDownloading` and `isDownloadAvailable` are being read.

Note: at a first read these seem to be the only places in which we read those state vars, if you read'em anywhere else, you should consider adding those call sites to the consideration.

This will help avoid a recomposition of the whole `DownloadItem`.

If you want to play a bit with recompositions, you can debug'em via Layout Inspector, which will let you know what is recomposing and how many times.

If I didn't answer the question let me know, I'll try to do better.
Also, check the best practice resource which I linked, it is really relevant and would also encourage you to check out [this ViewModel overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?hl=en) if you haven't adopted this approach in the past.
To finish, managing state correctly is essential in Compose, one technique that we use a lot is State Hoisting, take a read [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state-hoisting) to get your feet wet.

Comment: So I guess my confusion/concern comes from updating two booleans, does that mean it will recompose twice or just once after they both change?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the very late response!

That's actually a very nice question! I did some testing and as I suspected even if you provide 3 booleans from a viewModel to a Composable function and you toggle all their values on a button press, the Composable which reads their values recomposes just once (Had to actually try it to confirm this).